# HW Question: Is it possible to convert all the test scores without additional blocks in grading function?

Tags: python, function, return

I have this homework question asking to input 5 test scores and calculate the equivalent letter grade and then run an average and apply a letter grade to that as well.

I currently have a working program but I wanted to see if it's possible to get all the scores through just using one set of 'if' statements

```
def letter_grade(test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, average):
    if test1 >= 90 and test1 <=100:
        score1 = "A"
    elif test1 >= 80 and test1 <= 89:
        score1 = "B"
    elif test1 >= 70 and test1 <= 79:
        score1 = "C"
    elif test1 >= 60 and test1 <= 69:
        score1 = "D"
    elif test1 < 60:
        score1 = "F"


    if test2 >= 90 and test2 <=100:
        score2 = "A"
    elif test2 >= 80 and test2 <= 89:
        score2 = "B"
    elif test2 >= 70 and test2 <= 79:
        score2 = "C"
    elif test2 >= 60 and test2 <= 69:
        score2 = "D"
    elif test2 < 60:
        score2 = "F"


    if test3 >= 90 and test3 <=100:
        score3 = "A"
    elif test3 >= 80 and test3 <= 89:
        score3 = "B"
    elif test3 >= 70 and test3 <= 79:
        score3 = "C"
    elif test3 >= 60 and test3 <= 69:
        score3 = "D"
    elif test3 < 60:
        score3 = "F"


    if test4 >= 90 and test4 <=100:
        score4 = "A"
    elif test4 >= 80 and test4 <= 89:
        score4 = "B"
    elif test4 >= 70 and test4 <= 79:
        score4 = "C"
    elif test4 >= 60 and test4 <= 69:
        score4 = "D"
    elif test4 < 60:
        score4 = "F"



    if test5 >= 90 and test5 <=100:
        score5 = "A"
    elif test5 >= 80 and test5 <= 89:
        score5 = "B"
    elif test5 >= 70 and test5 <= 79:
        score5 = "C"
    elif test5 >= 60 and test5 <= 69:
        score5 = "D"
    elif test5 < 60:
        score5 = "F"


    if average >= 90 and average <=100:
        avgScore = "A"
    elif average >= 80 and average <= 89:
        avgScore = "B"
    elif average >= 70 and average <= 79:
        avgScore = "C"
    elif average >= 60 and average <= 69:
        avgScore = "D"
    elif average < 60:
        avgScore = "F"
    return score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, avgScore
```

I would like the function to return the letter scores in a more efficient way if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Just define the function, and then use it to grade every test and the average:

```
def letter_grade(score):
    if 90 <= score <= 100:
        grade = "A"
    elif 80 <= score <= 89:
        grade = "B"
    elif 70 <= score <= 79:
        grade = "C"
    elif 60 <= score <= 69:
        grade = "D"
    elif score < 60:
        grade = "F"
    return grade


tests = [50, 60, 65, 99, 25]

for test in tests:
    print(f"score: {test}, grade: {letter_grade(test)}")

print("average grade:", letter_grade(sum(tests) / len(tests)))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> score: 50, grade: F
> score: 60, grade: D
> score: 65, grade: D
> score: 99, grade: A
> score: 25, grade: F
> average grade: F
> ```